# hdfs normally working but with sudo it shows command not found

Tags: command-line, 20.04, sudo, hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop3.1.1 and i have set ./bashrc file and all the other necessary files. while applying hdfs i am facing this situation shown in the picture.
[this image shows commands I have performed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBa7J.png)

Comment: For security reasons, `sudo` uses its own `secure_path` instead of your user's (or root's) `PATH`

Answer (score 0):

You can soft link hdfs command in /usr/sbin for example so you can able to call hdfs from root user as well.

or you can login in root user and change the same .bashrc and add hadoop command your path.

then you can succeed with hdfs with root. but think before working with root.